# How to create a module to insert some analytics code in the footer of website pages?

Tags: 7, hooks

I want to create a module for Drupal 7, with a simple scope. It's just to insert the analytics code in the footer of website pages and with an option to exclude some pages if required.

I just need a module configuration page with 1 text field to enter the Analytics ID. And a text area below it, just like in blocks configuration page, which allows you to show the block on specific pages.

After this info is saved, the code should be inserted in the footer of each page, with that Analytics ID.

Can anybody tell me what hooks I will need to implement this functionality?

Comment: What are you try to test? Just if you could build it yourself? (if it's not just for train your skills why not use the [Google Analytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) Module?)

Comment: Yes I want to learn, how to accomplish this functionality

Comment: user5482 posted what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two links should get you started:

https://www.drupal.org/node/206761

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking at the [Code Examples For Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples). Excerpt from its project page:

> ... contains many modules which hopefully illustrate best practices for implementing various Drupal APIs. These modules can be enabled individually, and will typically add menu items to your site, which should guide you through their features. You can then look through the code to see what they are doing.
>
> Developers can learn how to use a particular API quickly by experimenting with the examples, and adapt them for their own use.